# Storybook Addon StoryShots for Angular 12

Tags: angular, jestjs, storybook, angular-storybook, snapshot-testing

I will install Snapshot Testing with Storybook under Angular 12.
I install jest `$ yarn add --dev jest jest-preset-angular @types/jest` and make Settings

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts"]
}
```

and set setupJest.ts Data with only one line `import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';`.

Thats the Jest Setup. This Works for me.

The problem is the Storyshorts Addon from Storybook. I install Storyshorts `yarn add @storybook/addon-storyshots --dev` and create file `src/storyshorts.test.js` with this code:

```
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';

initStoryshots();
```

When I run the command `jest` in my Angular Project I become this error:

```
Cannot find module 'jest-preset-angular/build/setup-jest' from 'node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/ts3.9/frameworks/angular/loader.js'
  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
  at setupAngularJestPreset (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/ts3.9/frameworks/angular/loader.js:36:14)
  at Object.load (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/ts3.9/frameworks/angular/loader.js:43:5)
  at Object.loadFramework [as default] (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/ts3.9/frameworks/frameworkLoader.js:26:19)
  at Object.testStorySnapshots [as default] (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/ts3.9/api/index.js:42:39)
```

My Package.json has this entries:

```
...
"@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^6.3.12",
"@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
"jest": "^27.3.1",
"jest-preset-angular": "^10.0.1",
```

and Angular 12 packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT (28/11/2023)**

Since Storybook 7.6, Storyhots is now officially deprecated, is no longer being maintained, and will be removed in the next major release of Storybook.

You should migrate your snapshots test from Storyshots to Storybook's test runner with the help of this [migration guide](https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-tests/storyshots-migration-guide).

**EDIT : >= Angular 16**

**Context**

- With jest-preset-angular 13.1.X
- With @storybook/addon-storyshots 7.X.X

You'll not be able to run Storyshots anymore due to a bug (`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'imports' of 'analyzedMetadata' as it is undefined.`)
A PR is currently open to fix it (https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/23555).

I’ll provide the new jest configuration when the PR will be merged.

Also, you should note that StoryShots will be deprecated in a near futur and will be replaced by the [test-runner](https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/writing-tests/test-runner) ([a migration guide will be provided by the core team, stay tune](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/22263)).

Therefore, Storyshots will not be improved / changed (except by the community until its deprecation date).

**EDIT: >= Angular 13 :**

**Context**

- With `jest-preset-angular 12.X.X`
- With `@storybook/addon-storyshots 6.5.X`

As I kept `Karma/Jasmine` for unit testing (bigger community), `Jest` is only for snapshots tests with `Storybook`, so my `jest.config.js` is under the `.storybook` folder and I created a specific `tsconfig` file.

**jest.config.js**

```js
const { defaults: jestNgPreset } = require('jest-preset-angular/presets');

/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  rootDir: '../',
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/.storybook/setup-jest.ts'],
  // Ensure to run ngcc for uncompliant Ivy lib
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
       ...jestNgPreset.globals['ts-jest'],
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/.storybook/tsconfig.storyshots.json',
    },
  },
  transform: {
    ...jestNgPreset.transform,
    '^.+\\.stories\\.mdx?$': '<rootDir>/.storybook/empty.js',
  },
  // Don't transform files in node_modules, except those which match those patterns
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$|@storybook/addon-docs/angular|@angular|primeng|angular-auth-oidc-client)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
'jest-preset-angular/build/setup-jest': 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest',
'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularNoNgAttributesSnapshotSerializer':
  'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularSnapshotSerializer':
  'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
'jest-preset-angular/build/HTMLCommentSerializer':
  'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.storyshots.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "files": ["./typings.d.ts"]
}
```

**empty.js**

```
/**
 * This file is used to prevent mdx files importation during snapshot testing with Jest (see jest.config.js).
 * I tried with testPathIgnorePatterns or storyKindRegex, but impossible.
 */
module.exports = {
  process: function () {
    return { code: '' };
  },
};
```

=== **Original (Angular 12)** ===

Welcome in hell :D !

For your problem : storyshots addon try to load `setup-jest.ts` file from a bad path. Since `jest-preset-angular` version 9, `setup-jest.ts` is no longer located into `jest-preset-angular/build/` folder (and this is not the only impacted file).
Storyshots addon doesn't handle this change yet, so you can use `moduleNameMapper` from jest config to rewrite path and fix your issue.

See my `jest.config.js` as example :

```js
require('jest-preset-angular/ngcc-jest-processor');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@storybook/addon-docs))',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'jest-preset-angular/build/setup-jest': 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularNoNgAttributesSnapshotSerializer':
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularSnapshotSerializer':
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/HTMLCommentSerializer':
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  },
};
```

If you need more explanation, ask me :)

Comment: What is in your tsconfig.storyshots.json ?

Comment: I'll show you my config, I'll edit my answer in few minutes

Comment: I tried to follow your solution but it results in the following error message: ```Module <rootDir>/.storybook/empty.js in the transform option was not found.``` (and the file really doesn't exist). I wonder if there is any fully working example for Angular 15 with Storybook with the storyshots addon but still using Karma for Unit Testing. I was only able to find pieces here and there but all seemed to be configured differently and I can't work out how to put them as I lack the experience with Storybook.`

Executed with ```jest storybook.test.ts --config=.storybook/jest.config.js```

Comment: Hey ! 

Sorry for the delayed answer....

empty.js file is a custom file that I created, maybe you don't need it.
I created it to prevent mdx files importation during snapshot testing with Jest

Comment: @patrickuhlmlann  I'm trying to edit my response to update jest config for Ng16 but StoryShots are broken (with Ng16 and Storybook v7.1). 
Are you in v16 ?

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER: No sorry. We are not using StoryShots anymore.